# How to ensure that a code is running on main thread in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, program-entry-point

It's easy to do so in objective c but I do not know how to do so in vb.net

update:
I know about control.invoke. But control.invoke requires a control that may change from program to program. What would be the easier way?

So yes program is winform. However I need a solution that does not depend on any specific control. If that's the case actually I do not need things to be run on main thread do I?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Console? Winforms?

Comment: What UI are you using: WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: What do you mean by "main thread"?  Is the UI thread considered the main thread?  Why is it important to ensure you are on the main thread?

Comment: yes UI thread, without referencing any control though because I want the code to run on multiple different forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No body does this right. So I did the only way I know. Have a global variable and synchronize that global variable. It doesn't guarantee that the thread will run at the same UI thread. However, it guarantee that the codes won't run simultaneously. Which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "ensure". Do you want to be able to check from the running thread if it is on the main thread or do you want to programatically say before code is actually run that it must only run on the main thread.

Are you trying to update the UI from a secondary thread? If so, there are usually better ways (depending on the application type) to do that than checking the thread itself. For instance, in a WinForms app you can actually safely ask most controls if a cross thread call is needed by checking the `InvokeRequired`. If true then you can pass the control a `Delegate` to run your code which will put it on the main UI thread for you.

Comment: I know about control.invoke. But control.invoke requires a control that may change from program to program. What would be the easier way?